# float alternative for email clients

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-email, email-client

What is the float alternative for the email clients?

Here is what I have using float. And I want the alternative approach to preserve the behavior exactly.

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftText">
    left text
  </div>
  <div class="rightText">
    right text right text
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.leftText {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: yellow;
}

.rightText {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: cyan;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/4gaxcr2b/19/)

Here is what I tried to do using available in all email clients `text-align` and `calc` (`calc` is available according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054654/is-calc-supported-in-html-email)).

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftText">
    left text
  </div>
  <div class="rightText">
    right text right text
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.leftText {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: yellow;
}

.rightText {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: calc(100% - 58px);
  min-width: 122px;

  border: 1px solid green;
  background: cyan;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/4gaxcr2b/34/)

This approach does not work in a way that when the right text is moved to its own line the words does not wrap due to the `min-width` being set. If it would be possible to add word wrapping after the right text moved to its own line that solution would be what I seek.

According to [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/display/) Outlook does not support `display: table` and after testing it turns out to be true. So, please, do not advise me to use the `display: table` or similar display (like `inline-table`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell` etc.).

[image]

Comment: Outlook email clients dont like div's

Comment: @Syfer, what should I use instead?

Comment: Stick to tables only. Go with what gwally has suggested

Comment: @Syfer, table does not allow content to go to the next line.

Comment: Word break is your friend.

Comment: @Syfer, ok let me explain the use case I need here. I have an element on left and an element on right. The left element always sticks to left, the right element always sticks to right. Now if the screen width is too small to fit simultaneously both left and right elements I would like the right element go beneath the left element. Is it possible to achieve such a behavior using table?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, it is possible to use tables to simulate floats. Below is the code using **hybrid method** of coding. it works the way you want it to.

Note: CSS is just to show you how the stacking would work. Below code can work the same without media queries.

```css
.wrapper{width:680px;outline: 1px solid #f00;}
.wrapper div{outline: 1px solid blue;}
 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrapper{width:100% !important;}
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="wrapper">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:0px;text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px;">
  
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="680" align="center"><tr><td><![endif]--> 
  
    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:340px; min-width:200px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td style="font-size:10px;">left</td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td><![endif]--> 
    
    <div style="display:inline-block; max-width:340px; min-width:200px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td style="font-size:10px;">right</td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
    
  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--> 
  
   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this is the answer you where looking for.

Cheers

Comment: Outlook does not support `inline-block`.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov Yes it doesn't on div's that's why there is a ghost table around it. The above code works flawlessly unless the email WYSIWYG editor is old and doesn't like the comments (experienced that before)

Answer (score 2):

`float` works with nearly every email client except IBM Notes 9, Outlook 2007–16 (desktop PC) and Windows 10.

In email clients where `float` doesn't work, to float something right, as an example, for a `<table>` I use either `<table align="right">` or `<table style="text-align: right;">`

Good luck.

Comment: Table is far from being the same as float. The cell does not go to the next line on small screens for example.

Comment: `div` does not have universal support in email. The same clients that do not support `float` do not support `div`. You can create a `table` to act as an object you can float around an email. I thought that would be clear to a seasoned developer. Email development is not web development. It uses similar technologies but in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick I come up with.

html

```
<div class="l">
  left text
</div>
<div class="m">

</div>
<div class="r">
  rigth text rigth text
</div>
```

css

```
.l {
  display: inline-block;
}

.m {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 180px);
}

.r {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/738/).

It is straightforward. I need to always have a distance between left and right component as much as possible and it is depicted in the `calc` property of the fictitious element.

Comment: Outlook email clients dont like div's