# Inline CSS, @media tag solution for an email template

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

For an email template I want an output like this
**On Wide Screen**
[image]

but **on small screen** like mobile or `@media (max-width: 768px)` I want output like this
[image]

to achieve this in internal CSS I used bootstrap

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mahm0udwally/all-flat/256/User-icon.png" alt="img1" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
```

but I want to do it using Inline CSS, the real problem is how can I use styles of both `col-xs-6` and  `col-sm-4` in one single tag?

---

### [With Internal CSS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DHysdZBdsc6bKcqEbYzQVGFFQ1T3iUV4) and [With Inline CSS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ZzUAXckfeEyrFQDWgLq7bx_XXu7VuIl)

PS: @media tags are not allowed in Inline CSS. Its an email template that's why using inline CSS is necessary.

Comment: One solution would be using javascript and  the [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this using inline CSS?

Comment: @enxaneta yes, but Its an email template, I have heard that mostly email clients block JS and doesn't allow it.

Comment: @MTCoster Basically its an email template, so its necessary to use Inline CSS

Comment: If it’s an email, it’s probably also necessary to use tables for layout, but [that doesn’t mean responsive designs are impossible](https://css-tricks.com/ideas-behind-responsive-emails/).

Comment: @MTCoster should I fix them instead of using responsive? because I didn't think there is any solution to do this without `@media` and JS.

Comment: The link in my comment demonstrates at least one method for adding responsive layouts to emails.

Comment: You can tryout some email templates, for example from foundation. https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/email-templates.html.

Comment: You can do this easily with hybrid method of coding. Your stacking will be done on screen size and media queries can be used to beautify layout. Check out the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841836/float-alternative-for-email-clients/52885379#52885379).

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block inside text-align:center

```
<div style="text-align:center">
     <img style= "width:100px;display:inline-block" >
    <img style= "width:100px;display:inline-block">
    <img style= "width:100px;display:inline-block">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/70qfn3d8/

Comment: In this example you have used two separate blocks and fixed length, but in my scenario the situation is with one block, dynamically detect device width and adjust accordingly! without using @media tag and JS

Comment: The two blocks (small_screen, wide_screen) represent different size devices. You can put any width in there and it will work. The internal html is the same for either case.

Comment: Put any width? how can I put dynamic width? I am not allowed to use classes, only inline style attribute.

Comment: The only HTML you use is what is written here in the answer. You don't supply any width at all, except the width of the images. I added the outside blocks to represent the different devices. You wouldn't use those in your email template.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on CSS. JavaScript will not work in email as it is stripped out and disabled by most email clients.

This answer is based on using the email template, Cerberus. Although you could use it on any responsive modern email template, I suppose.

What you will need is several style sheet classes in a `@media` query, a table to act as a container, then a three column table.

Style Sheet:

```
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .email-container {
        width: 100% !important;
        margin: auto !important;
    }
    .stack-column-center {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        direction: ltr !important;
        float: left !important;
    }
    .stack-column-center-50 {
        width: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        direction: ltr !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
</style>
```

HTML Code:

```
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="email-container">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="outline: 1px solid #f00;">
            <tr>
                <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center-50">
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/170" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                <p style="margin: 0;"><strong>Column 1</strong><br />Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- Column : END -->
                <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center-50">
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/170" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                <p style="margin: 0;"><strong>Column 2</strong><br />Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- Column : END -->
                <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                <td width="33.33%" class="stack-column-center">
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center">
                                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/170" width="170" height="170" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; color: #555555;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                <p style="margin: 0;"><strong>Column 3</strong><br />Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <!-- Column : END -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tested this in Litmus and it works in every desktop-style email client and in mobile clients that support `@media` queries. If you download Cerberus, all you need to do is make two changes, add the class `.stack-column-center-50` and copy the table and paste it into the email body table. Other than adding Column 1, 2, 3 to the tables, I made no other changes.

Cerberus Template:
https://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/

**Edit**: You could combine the values of `col-xs-6` and `col-sm-4` into a new tag for `col-xs-6` under 600px. Or create a new tag if you want to preserve how the current classes work. My example will still work with new names.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using min-length external div and `width:33.33333333%; min-width: 92px;display:inline-block` on internal images.

demo https://jsfiddle.net/70qfn3d8/4/

```
<div style="min-width: 190px;">
     <div style="text-align:center">
          <img style= "-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;max-width: 170px !important; border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto;padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;min-height:1px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;width:33.33333333%; min-width: 92px;display:inline-block" src ="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mahm0udwally/all-flat/256/User-icon.png">
          <img style= "-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;max-width: 170px !important; border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto;padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;min-height:1px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;width:33.33333333%; min-width: 92px;display:inline-block" src ="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mahm0udwally/all-flat/256/User-icon.png">
          <img style= "-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;max-width: 170px !important; border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block;max-width:100%;height:auto;padding:4px;line-height:1.42857143;background-color:#fff;border-radius:4px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;min-height:1px;padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;width:33.33333333%; min-width: 92px;display:inline-block" src ="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mahm0udwally/all-flat/256/User-icon.png">
     </div>
</div>
```